# "No database selected" exception

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I am running following query

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=sa;port=3306;";
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
       conn.Open();
       cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hello.symbols` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',`animal` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));";
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And getting this exception `"No database selected"`

Any Idea how to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append the name of the database to the connection string

```
;Database=myDataBase
```

Comment: this way you should not need to issue the USE statement as Tomalak suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Issue a `USE databasename;` statement first.

MySQL docs: [12.8.4. `USE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)

Answer (score 1):

Insert database to connection string:

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=sa;port=3306;Database=YourDatabase";
```